# How to flash Android O image in Moto G4 Plus

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, motorola, lineageos

I have Moto G4 Plus device which has Android 7.0 - I want to flash Android O system image in Moto G4 Plus. I see https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html where system images are for Nexus, Pixel etc.

Motorola itself will take time to push updates to their devices so I am looking to push it manually.
Does anyone know if there is any system image for Moto G4 Plus ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll supplement the answer of @beeshyams: since Android O is still in Dev Preview phase, the source code is still incomplete, and no custom ROM (LineageOS, etc.) could even base their work off it. LineageOS (back in their CyanogenMod days) also stated time and again that they will not touch Dev Preview code.

To reinforce the fact: until Android O is officially released (name confirmed and source code out), there's no way you can taste it on an unsupported device.

P.S. Historically, there had been ports of Android L and M Dev Previews to other devices, based on the image released alone. However, 1) such ports are often conducted between devices of similar SoCs, 2) those ports are nowhere near stable and usable, and 3) they quickly become obsolete once the proper release source code arrives.

Comment: @beeshyams I only saw OP's comment under your answer and decided to write this up, since it'd be too long for a comment... To be honest, your answer is the one that's on point with OP's question.

Comment: @RahulGopi I understand the intention of of your edit, but I intentionally made the 3 points in-line since it's part of a P.S. The way I see it, making it a proper list would make it stand out, more so than the body.

Comment: I would add point 4) If you're not sure where to find a Dev build for your device, you probably shouldn't be attempting to flash it to your device unless you like shiny bricks. (Said by the guy with an IT background who's fiddled with hardware & software for 30+ years yet still struggles to make it through the rooting/flashing tutorials on XDA.)

Answer (score 8):

Impossible

If Moto themselves did not update your device, there is no way you can obtain an authentic system image. Even when your device is updated,  Motorola is very slow to update the latest image on it's website, and you would have to depend on images obtained through unofficial means hosted on sites like XDA

Related [Security Patch level old on Moto G5](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/176636/131553)

Comment: Do you have any link for unofficial system image on lineageos/cyanogenmod ?

Comment: Sorry, no. Best is to search on XDA